# can my Jenkinsfile contain only properties and no piepeline code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

All the tutorials that I have come across regarding writing a declarative pipeline suggest to include the stages and steps in the **Jenkinsfile**.

But I have noticed one of my seniors writing it the opposite way. He uses the Jenkinsfile just for defining all the properties, i.e. his Jenkinsfile is just a properties file, nothing more nothing less.

And for defining the pipeline he makes use of the shared library concepts where he writes his pipeline code in a file in the vars folder. I am not able to guess the wisdom behind this approach.

Nowhere over the internet did I come across anything similar.
Any guidance in this regard is highly appreciated. I am a beginner in the Jenkins world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As illustrated in [**Extending with Shared Libraries**](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), that approach (that I am using as well) allows to:

- keep a Jenkinsfile content to a *minimum*
- enforce a standard way of doing a particular job (as coded in the shared library)

That shared library becomes a template of a process for which you provide only values in your Jenkinsfile before delegating the actual execution to the pre-defined library.

The [OP Asif Kamran Malick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915738/asif-kamran-malick) note that the [documentation does include](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl):

> There is also a “builder pattern” trick using Groovy’s `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`, which permits Jenkinsfile to look slightly more like a configuration file than a program, but this is more complex and error-prone and is not recommended.

He then asks:

> Why did the blogger prefer that way when its actually discouraged in the official doc.

I checked and we are using also `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`.
The reason is in the part "permits Jenkinsfile to look slightly more like a configuration file than a program"

This avoids us having to define a JSON block, and keep the parameter as a series of `key=value` lines, easier to read.

A call to a shared library is then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library("MyLibraries") _
MyLibrary {
    config1 = 'value1'
    config2 = 'value2'
    ...
}
{
    anotherConfigA = 'valueA'
    anotherConfigB = 'valueB'...
    astep(
        ...
    )
}
```

*Then* your jenkins pipeline template in `MyLibraries/vars/MyLibrary.yml` can use those closure blocks:

```
def call(Closure configBlock, Closure body) {
    def config = [:]
    configBlock.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    configBlock.delegate = config
    configBlock()

    astep(
      ...
    ){
      if (body) { body() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Went through the documentation that you provided. From what I could understand , the docs suggests against the use of such pattern. My understanding is based on the statement **There is also a “builder pattern” trick using Groovy’s Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, which permits Jenkinsfile to look slightly more like a configuration file than a program, but this is more complex and error-prone and is not recommended.** Let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick I'll have to check tomorrow, but I don't believe we ar e=usnig that  Groovy’s Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST trick.

Comment: No issues. Just an FYI: My senior uses **Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST** in the shared library exactly as depicted in [this jenkins blog](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/04/21/dsl-plugins/) and reads the properties via the config. But here is again where question arises: **Why did the blogger prefer that way when its actually discouraged in the official doc.** These are the queries I have in my mind. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick I have edited the answer to address your question.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. So I believe its safe to assume that there's no major downside to using that approach and its just a matter of preference.

Comment: True, but try using json parts in your Jenkinsfile,  and the preference is quickly chosen ;)